# NeoVim Plugin not getting installed. (Using vim-plug)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

Please help me I am facing this weird issue while setting up my init.vim for my NeoVim. So the following is my init.vim file. That does not show any errors. But when I want to install the plugins. After I run `:PlugInstall` only vim-code-dark is getting Installed. The other Plugins i.e. vim-polyglot and NERDTree isn't getting installed. PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE tell me where have I gone wrong. I am stuck here since like 2 days but can't setup my Vim editor.

```
" Auto-Install vim-plug
if empty(glob('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  "autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
  "autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source $MYVIMRC
endif

"__________________________________________________________________________________________

" Vim-Editor Plugins
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plugged')
    Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
    Plug 'scrooloose/NERDTree'
    Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
call plug#end()

"__________________________________________________________________________________________

" General Editor Settings
" set leader key
let g:mapleader = "\<ALT>"

" vim basics
set encoding=utf-8
syntax enable
set relativenumber
set noswapfile
set scrolloff=4
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" vim basics
set encoding=utf-8
syntax enable
set relativenumber
set noswapfile
set scrolloff=4
set backspace=indent,eol,start


" indentation
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set fileformat=unix
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set nohlsearch
set nobackup
set nowrap
filetype plugin indent on

" autocompletion
set updatetime=300
"__________________________________________________________________________________________

" Vim Themes

call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plugged')
    Plug 'tomasiser/vim-code-dark'
call plug#end()

colorscheme codedark
let g:airline_theme = 'codedark'
```

Comment: @L3viathan You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `plug`-blocks, that'll confuse vim-plug. Move `vim-code-dark` into the earlier `plug`-block and delete the second one.