# Which directory does the neovim load vim-plug script on MacOS?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am switching from vim to neovim. According to https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug.

For Unix/Linux

```
sh -c 'curl -fLo "${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
       https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
```

`${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/nvim/site/autoload/` resolves to `~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/`.
However when neovim start it does not load the vim-plug script from here.

I have tried to manually setting `call plug#begin(~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/Plugged)` however, neovim does not seems to load from this folder.

I have also referred to this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634365/default-location-of-vim-plug-installed-plugins-for-neovim), however no luck.

Other link referred:
[Vim-plug error with neovim, Unkown function: plug#end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476622/vim-plug-error-with-neovim-unkown-function-plugend)
[NeoVim Plugin not getting installed. (Using vim-plug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483908/neovim-plugin-not-getting-installed-using-vim-plug)
[Neovim - 'plugged' directory cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828937/neovim-plugged-directory-cannot-be-found)